# Clarification needed regarding acceleration of a lift

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

Consider a lift(or an elevator, as Americans call it) which has a block in it, with the lift accelerating upwards. We are looking at this system from the ground frame.

Wouldn't the block's net acceleration be (g-a), as gravity is acting downwards, whereas the lift's acceleration is upward?

Similarly, when the lift accelerates downwards, the block should feel an acceleration of (g+a), but it is the complete opposite.
Why?

Comment: Do you want an intuitive explanation or a mathematical proof?

Comment: An intuitive explanation.

Comment: It's the same as feeling "heavy" when an elevator goes up and "light" when it goes down. What makes you think the accelerations of the block in each should be different from what it is really?

Comment: Your "heavy" and "light" example really does the job for me. I now understand the idea of what the block would be feeling. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard Newtonian physics the acceleration of the lift is just $\vec a$. There are two forces acting on the block. One is gravity $m\vec g$ and the other is the normal force $\vec N$.

Newton’s 2nd law says that the sum of the forces is the mass times the acceleration so $$\vec N + m\vec g=m\vec a$$

This is the vector expression regardless of if the lift is accelerating up or down. You can then look at the vertical component of this vector equation to solve it. Only then does the sign of the vertical component of $\vec g$ and $\vec a$ come in.

Comment: Yes, what you said is true, but this wasn't what I am confused about. I am confused about the acceleration of the block. Obviously, it would be (g+a) if both (lift and block) are moving downward, and (g-a) if moving upwards. But its the complete opposite. Why is that so?

Comment: the acceleration is always a, given the way the problem is structured.  It is never (g+a) or (g-a).  Were it to be (g+a), that would mean the elevator is accelerating down (not just going down), and within the elevator, something is accelerating the block towards the bottom of the elevator (in the elevator's frame)

Comment: @Haider the acceleration is just $\vec a$ in standard Newtonian mechanics

Comment: @Dale Oh, okay. So gravity only plays a part in mg (which is always downwards) and nowhere else. I now understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you are standing on a scale in a stationary elevator, gravity is pulling you down, compressing the spring in the scale.  That spring compresses until its upward force equals your weight, and you read your weight on the scale.  The upward force provided by the spring is actually the normal force that prevents you from sinking further down on the scale.

When the elevator accelerates up, there is an additional force causing that acceleration, and that force is added to the normal force on the spring, increasing the spring compression and the reading on the scale.  Due to this, the scale reading increases when the elevator accelerates you upward.  Obviously, the opposite happens when you are accelerating downward.